# Cgroup memory usage is different from sum of memory usage of sub cgroups

Tags: linux, docker, containers, cgroups

The memory usage I see here:

```
sudo cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes
```

is different the from the sum of memory usage of the sub cgroups, which I calculated by getting all the sub cgroups using the following command:

```
sudo ls -dltrh /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/*/
```

Then I took the sum of the `memory.usage_in_bytes` for all of these sub cgroups. From what I understand, these two values should match.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Comment: @kaylum This is a programming question since control groups are a fairly advanced programming interface, not something average administrator would be expected to fiddle with directly.